# VS Code auto import does not show suggestion for all components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, import

I am working on React native in Visual Studio code.

I use this [Auto Import Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) to get auto import bulb while typing. And yellow bulb also shown when i typed something and it is not imported.

**Problem** is, this plugin is not showing auto import popup for all things in React Native. (Like it never sense `ImageBackground` and many more...)

Is there some `configuration` that will make this happen?

**Expected** I want all components of React Native and its packages should be auto importable.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution or plugin for the auto importing of components? I'm having the same issue.